# How to simulate inner join on very large files in java (without running out of memory)

Tags: java, file-handling

I am trying to simulate SQL joins using java and very large text files (INNER, RIGHT OUTER and LEFT OUTER). The files have already been sorted using an external sort routine.

The issue I have is I am trying to find the most efficient way to deal with the INNER join part of the algorithm. Right now I am using two Lists to store the lines that have the same key and iterate through the set of lines in the right file once for every line in the left file (provided the keys still match). In other words, the join key is not unique in each file so would need to account for the Cartesian product situations ...

```
left_01, 1
left_02, 1
right_01, 1
right_02, 1
right_03, 1

left_01 joins to right_01 using key 1
left_01 joins to right_02 using key 1
left_01 joins to right_03 using key 1
left_02 joins to right_01 using key 1
left_02 joins to right_02 using key 1
left_02 joins to right_03 using key 1
```

My concern is one of memory. I will run out of memory if i use the approach below but still want the inner join part to work fairly quickly. What is the best approach to deal with the INNER join part keeping in mind that these files may potentially be huge

```
public class Joiner {

  private void join(BufferedReader left, BufferedReader right, BufferedWriter output) throws Throwable {

    BufferedReader _left = left;
    BufferedReader _right = right;
    BufferedWriter _output = output;
    Record _leftRecord;
    Record _rightRecord;

    _leftRecord = read(_left);
    _rightRecord = read(_right);

    while( _leftRecord != null && _rightRecord != null ) {

      if( _leftRecord.getKey() < _rightRecord.getKey() ) {
        write(_output, _leftRecord, null);
        _leftRecord = read(_left);
      }
      else if( _leftRecord.getKey() > _rightRecord.getKey() ) {
        write(_output, null, _rightRecord);
        _rightRecord = read(_right);
      }
      else {
        List<Record> leftList = new ArrayList<Record>();
        List<Record> rightList = new ArrayList<Record>();

        _leftRecord = readRecords(leftList, _leftRecord, _left);
        _rightRecord = readRecords(rightList, _rightRecord, _right);

        for( Record equalKeyLeftRecord : leftList ){
          for( Record equalKeyRightRecord : rightList ){
            write(_output, equalKeyLeftRecord, equalKeyRightRecord);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if( _leftRecord != null ) {
      write(_output, _leftRecord, null);
      _leftRecord = read(_left);
      while(_leftRecord != null) {
        write(_output, _leftRecord, null);
        _leftRecord = read(_left);        
      }
    }
    else {  
      if( _rightRecord != null ) {
        write(_output, null, _rightRecord);
        _rightRecord = read(_right);
        while(_rightRecord != null) {
          write(_output, null, _rightRecord);
          _rightRecord = read(_right);
        }
      }     
    }
    _left.close();
    _right.close();
    _output.flush();
    _output.close();
  }

  private Record read(BufferedReader reader) throws Throwable {
    Record record = null;

    String data = reader.readLine();
    if( data != null ) {
      record = new Record(data.split("\t"));
    }
    return record;
  }

  private Record readRecords(List<Record> list, Record record, BufferedReader reader) throws Throwable {
    int key = record.getKey();
    list.add(record);
    record = read(reader);
    while( record != null && record.getKey() == key) {
      list.add(record);
      record = read(reader);
    }
    return record;    
  }

  private void write(BufferedWriter writer, Record left, Record right) throws Throwable {   
    String leftKey = (left == null ? "null" : Integer.toString(left.getKey()));
    String leftData = (left == null ? "null" : left.getData());
    String rightKey = (right == null ? "null" : Integer.toString(right.getKey()));
    String rightData = (right == null ? "null" : right.getData());

    writer.write("[" + leftKey + "][" + leftData + "][" + rightKey + "][" + rightData + "]\n");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

          BufferedReader leftReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LEFT.DAT"));
          BufferedReader rightReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("RIGHT.DAT"));
          BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("OUTPUT.DAT"));

      Joiner joiner = new Joiner();
      joiner.join(leftReader, rightReader, output);
    } 
        catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

After applying the ideas from the proposed answer, I changed the loop to this

```
private void join(RandomAccessFile left, RandomAccessFile right, BufferedWriter output) throws Throwable {

    long _pointer = 0;

    RandomAccessFile _left = left;
    RandomAccessFile _right = right;

    BufferedWriter _output = output;

    Record _leftRecord;
    Record _rightRecord;

    _leftRecord = read(_left);
    _rightRecord = read(_right);

    while( _leftRecord != null && _rightRecord != null ) {

        if( _leftRecord.getKey() < _rightRecord.getKey() ) {
            write(_output, _leftRecord, null);
            _leftRecord = read(_left);
        }
        else if( _leftRecord.getKey() > _rightRecord.getKey() ) {
            write(_output, null, _rightRecord);             
            _pointer = _right.getFilePointer();
            _rightRecord = read(_right);
        }
        else {          
            long _tempPointer = 0;
            int key = _leftRecord.getKey();                                                         
            while( _leftRecord != null && _leftRecord.getKey() == key ) {
                _right.seek(_pointer);
                _rightRecord = read(_right);
                while( _rightRecord != null && _rightRecord.getKey() == key ) {
                    write(_output, _leftRecord, _rightRecord );
                    _tempPointer = _right.getFilePointer();
                    _rightRecord = read(_right); 
                }
                _leftRecord = read(_left);
            }
            _pointer = _tempPointer;
        }
    }

    if( _leftRecord != null ) {
        write(_output, _leftRecord, null);
        _leftRecord = read(_left);
        while(_leftRecord != null) {
            write(_output, _leftRecord, null);
            _leftRecord = read(_left);              
        }
    }
    else {  
        if( _rightRecord != null ) {
            write(_output, null, _rightRecord);
            _rightRecord = read(_right);
            while(_rightRecord != null) {
                write(_output, null, _rightRecord);
                _rightRecord = read(_right);
            }
        }           
    }
    _left.close();
    _right.close();
    _output.flush();
    _output.close();
}
```

*UPDATE*
While this approach worked, it was terribly slow and so I have modified this to create files as buffers and this works very well. Here is the update ...

```
private long getMaxBufferedLines(File file) throws Throwable {
    long freeBytes = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 2;     
    return (freeBytes / (file.length() / getLineCount(file)));
}

private void join(File left, File right, File output, JoinType joinType) throws Throwable {

    BufferedReader leftFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(left));
    BufferedReader rightFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(right));
    BufferedWriter outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
    long maxBufferedLines = getMaxBufferedLines(right);

    Record leftRecord;
    Record rightRecord;

    leftRecord = read(leftFile);
    rightRecord = read(rightFile);

    while( leftRecord != null && rightRecord != null ) {

        if( leftRecord.getKey().compareTo(rightRecord.getKey()) < 0) {
            if( joinType == JoinType.LeftOuterJoin 
                    || joinType == JoinType.LeftExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin ) { 
                write(outputFile, leftRecord, null);
            }
            leftRecord = read(leftFile);
        }
        else if( leftRecord.getKey().compareTo(rightRecord.getKey()) > 0 ) {
            if( joinType == JoinType.RightOuterJoin 
                    || joinType == JoinType.RightExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin ) {
                write(outputFile, null, rightRecord);
            }
            rightRecord = read(rightFile);
        }
        else if( leftRecord.getKey().compareTo(rightRecord.getKey()) == 0 ) {
            String key = leftRecord.getKey(); 
            List<File> rightRecordFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
            List<Record> rightRecordList = new ArrayList<Record>();
            rightRecordList.add(rightRecord);
            rightRecord = consume(key, rightFile, rightRecordList, rightRecordFileList, maxBufferedLines);

            while( leftRecord != null && leftRecord.getKey().compareTo(key) == 0 ) {
                processRightRecords(outputFile, leftRecord, rightRecordFileList, rightRecordList, joinType);
                leftRecord = read(leftFile);
            }

            // need a dispose for deleting files in list
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("DATA IS NOT SORTED");
        }
    }

    if( leftRecord != null ) {
        if( joinType == JoinType.LeftOuterJoin 
                || joinType == JoinType.LeftExclusiveJoin
                || joinType == JoinType.FullExclusiveJoin
                || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin ) {
            write(outputFile, leftRecord, null);
        }
        leftRecord = read(leftFile);
        while(leftRecord != null) {
            if( joinType == JoinType.LeftOuterJoin 
                    || joinType == JoinType.LeftExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin ) {
                write(outputFile, leftRecord, null);
            }
            leftRecord = read(leftFile);              
        }
    }
    else {  
        if( rightRecord != null ) {
            if( joinType == JoinType.RightOuterJoin 
                    || joinType == JoinType.RightExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullExclusiveJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin ) {
                write(outputFile, null, rightRecord);
            }
            rightRecord = read(rightFile);
            while(rightRecord != null) {
                if( joinType == JoinType.RightOuterJoin 
                        || joinType == JoinType.RightExclusiveJoin
                        || joinType == JoinType.FullExclusiveJoin
                        || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin ) {
                    write(outputFile, null, rightRecord);
                }
                rightRecord = read(rightFile);
            }
        }           
    }
    leftFile.close();
    rightFile.close();
    outputFile.flush();
    outputFile.close();
}

public void processRightRecords(BufferedWriter outputFile, Record leftRecord, List<File> rightFiles, List<Record> rightRecords, JoinType joinType) throws Throwable {

    for(File rightFile : rightFiles) {
        BufferedReader rightReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rightFile));
        Record rightRecord = read(rightReader);
        while(rightRecord != null){

            if( joinType == JoinType.LeftOuterJoin 
                    || joinType == JoinType.RightOuterJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin
                    || joinType == JoinType.InnerJoin ) {               

                write(outputFile, leftRecord, rightRecord);
            }
            rightRecord = read(rightReader);
        }
        rightReader.close();
    }

    for(Record rightRecord : rightRecords) {
        if( joinType == JoinType.LeftOuterJoin 
                || joinType == JoinType.RightOuterJoin
                || joinType == JoinType.FullOuterJoin
                || joinType == JoinType.InnerJoin ) {               

            write(outputFile, leftRecord, rightRecord);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * consume all records having key (either to a single list or multiple files) each file will 
 * store a buffer full of data. The right record returned represents the outside flow (key is 
 * already positioned to next one or null) so we can't use this record in below while loop or 
 * within this block in general when comparing current key. The trick is to keep consuming 
 * from a List. When it becomes empty, re-fill it from the next file until all files have 
 * been consumed (and the last node in the list is read). The next outside iteration will be 
 * ready to be processed (either it will be null or it points to the next biggest key
 * @throws Throwable 
 * 
 */
private Record consume(String key, BufferedReader reader, List<Record> records, List<File> files, long bufferMaxRecordLines ) throws Throwable {
    boolean processComplete = false;
    Record record = records.get(records.size() - 1);

    while(!processComplete){
        long recordCount = records.size();
        if( record.getKey().compareTo(key) == 0 ){
            record = read(reader);                
            while( record != null && record.getKey().compareTo(key) == 0 && recordCount < bufferMaxRecordLines ) {
                records.add(record);
                recordCount++;
                record = read(reader);
            }
        }
        processComplete = true;
        // if record is null, we are done
        if( record != null ) {

            // if the key has changed, we are done
            if( record.getKey().compareTo(key) == 0 ) {

                // Same key means we have exhausted the buffer.
                // Dump entire buffer into a file. The list of file 
                // pointers will keep track of the files ...                    
                processComplete = false;
                dumpBufferToFile(records, files);
                records.clear();
                records.add(record);
            }
        }
    }
    return record;
}

/**
 * Dump all records in List of Record objects to a file. Then, add that 
 * file to List of File objects
 * 
 * NEED TO PLACE A LIMIT ON NUMBER OF FILE POINTERS (check size of file list)
 * 
 * @param records
 * @param files
 * @throws Throwable 
 */
private void dumpBufferToFile(List<Record> records, List<File> files) throws Throwable {
    String prefix = "joiner_" + files.size() + 1;
    String suffix = ".dat";
    File file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, new File("cache"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));       

    for( Record record : records ) {
        writer.write( record.dump() );
    }

    files.add(file);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) allows you to remember the some locations and return to it

Comment: My understanding is this is used for binary files, not lines of text (in my case tab delimited with newlines at the end of each row)

Comment: you can do a [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29) and it will work fine ;)

Comment: OK, so I will need to convert the right file to be an instance of RandomAccessFile, and when i do the inner join part, I keep a file pointer to the current row (using getFilePointer) and with each iteration, call seek(pointer) to return to that position. Is this the idea and is this the most efficient way if so?

Comment: are the files sorted on the key?

Comment: yes, as mentioned previously, I have sorted these using an external sort routine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10486/discussion-between-constantin-and-ratchet-freak)

Comment: Err... why?  In any case, I'd recommend looking at the source for one or more of the in-memory RDBMSs written in Java, which thus actually do it.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse - this particular program supports the processing of files, not database tables. What you suggest would require that I bulk insert both files into an embedded database before executing the join. The overhead of these initial inserts and subsequently writing the results out back to files might be costly in terms of performance

Comment: @Constantin - "The overhead of these initial inserts and subsequently writing the results out back to files might be costly in terms of performance" - so is sorting large text files on an arbitrary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a random [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

```
private void join(RandomAccessFile left, RandomAccessFile right, BufferedWriter output) throws Throwable {

    long rightIndex = right.getFilePointer();

    Record leftRecord = read(left);
    Record rightRecord;

    while((leftRecord )!=null){
        right.seek(rightIndex);

        while((rightRecord = read(right))!=null && leftRecord.getKey() > rightRecord.getKey()){
            //skip right until it can match left
            // store pointer because we don't need to return to earlier
            rightIndex = right.getFilePointer();
        }

        while(rightRecord !=null && leftRecord.getKey()==rightRecord.getKey()){
            write(_output, leftRecord, rightRecord );
            rightRecord = read(right))
        }
        leftRecord = read(left);
        //you can test the need to skip this left record if you keep the previous key and the current rightRecord.getKey()
    }
}
```

this will be a O(n+m) time and O(1) space algorithm

Comment: I have taken your idea and it seems to work ...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use "File Cache"?

Caching is supposed to be used when you have some layer with faster accessing ability to reduce time on the slower layers.

So if you read files through network, then caching via file system makes sense because local file system will be faster than network. If you are working on file system, then the faster level will be memory, and BufferedReader will handle memory caching for you. You can write your own wrapper CustomBufferredReader for BufferedReader to control more precisely how many records you want to read in advance and put in memory. To do this properly you need to research on the hardware/disk you are using to figure out how to best prefetch the records.

In your case, you are caching file system operations on file system operations. Doesn't make sense to me. I would not call this caching at all. This would help you only when you are caching intermediate work (like when you do dynamic programming), but it is not the case because the records have been sorted externally via external sorting as you have mentioned. There is no intermediate work.

And you mention cartesian product in the inner join part, if the records are all sorted by external sorting, there is no need to worry about cartesian products, you simply do zig-zag linear scan between the left record list and the right recrod list.

Comment: I am not understanding your zig-zag linear scan idea. Can you elaborate on how these lists are created without the use of additional memory (as I show in the original question using for loops against two ArrayLists - which is what i do not want)